# Getting the max template instantation deph used during compilation

Tags: c++, c++11, g++4.8

As the title says, **is there any compiler logging settings which provides the max instantation deph reached by the compiler during compilation?**

If the compilation exceds the max template deph (Which GCC's default value is 900 in C++11 mode), compilation fails. But what I need is to get the maximum template instantation depth which the compiler has reached during a successfull compilation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`g++` does have such an option, but it isn't enabled by default on kubuntu, for example.

The following is part of `gcc/cp/tree.c` from `gcc-4.8.1` (and is therefore licensed under the GPL):

```
void
cxx_print_statistics (void)
{
  print_search_statistics ();
  print_class_statistics ();
  print_template_statistics ();
  if (GATHER_STATISTICS)
    fprintf (stderr, "maximum template instantiation depth reached: %d\n",
             depth_reached);
}
```

You can get those statistics when adding `-fdump-statistics -fstats` to your command line, *but* `GATHER_STATISTICS` has to be enabled at the time you compile `gcc`, so you will probably have to rebuild `gcc` in order to get the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: One day have spent and there is no more answers. I was waiting to a successfull answer (An answer which works in my current situation/compiler-configuration). I had readed your answer yesterday, and I liked it. So finally this is the only possible answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, even the line that *sets* `depth_reached` in `pt.c` is only enabled with `GATHER_STATISTICS`, so there is probably no other way.